# Vagrant config.ssh.forward_agent = true only works for vagrant user?

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I'm trying to write a provisioning script for Vagrant that pulls all software sources to the machine.
However, pretty soon, I found out that I needed SSH keys to do this.
I would like to reuse existing keys.
With the `config.ssh.forward_agent` option it is possible to forward these keys to the Vagrant guest.

In the provisioning script, I also created a user (just like the production env).
With this user I would like to pull sources to its home directory.

However, I found out that this key-forwarding doesn't work in that case.
Now, I found out only the `vagrant` user has access to these keys!!

Is that what must be expected? And is there a way to solve this issue?
Can I forward the keys to my specific guest user? 
Or should I do all provisioning with the vagrant user? and then add user, move stuff around and chown it to the new user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vagrant runs its actions with user `vagrant` by default.
So when you run provision, it will be user `vagrant` that will be used for SSH.

If you want to use another username, you need that username to exist on your box before your first `vagrant up` and have the `config.ssh.username` setting.

You can also do something like:

1. Provision machine like you do now (and create new user)
2. Copy .ssh directory from vagrant user home to new user's home directory
3. Add new user to sudoers
4. Add `config.ssh.username` setting to Vagrantfile with the new username
5. Run `vagrant reload`

Now Vagrant should use the new user for provision

However I don't recommend second approach at all since it includes manual step.